# Forum email address display issue

Tags: php, forum

I created a web forum with the script below. I am able to receive inquiries from my site; however, the visitor's email address is not showing in the email sent from the webmaster. I would like to have some guidance here to fix the problem.

Here is my PHP script:

```
<?php $name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$formcontent="From: $name \n Message: $message";
$recipient = "abc@gmail.com";
$subject = "Contact Form";
mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent) or die("Error!");
echo "Thank You!";
?>
```

Here is what I got from the webmaster:
From: xx
Message: xx

No email address listed in the email sent by the webmaster.

I found some similar scripts on the web with two additional rows:

```
$mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
```

This actually gives me an Error output.

How can I fix the issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could add headers to the mail function.

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$formcontent="From: $name \n Message: $message";
$recipient = "abc@gmail.com";
$subject = "Contact Form";

$headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "From: <$email>" . "\r\n";

mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $headers);
```

FYI - I would santize and validate all POST values before using them in this manner

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am still getting an error message. The inquiry didn't go through.

Answer (score 0):

The third parameter of `mail()` is just the actual body of the message, which you have saved as `$message`. The **fourth** variable is where you define the headers, and is where you define who the message is `From`. Note that you don't actually need to pass the message as a header, and as such, your variable `$formcontent`, shouldn't contain your `From:` header. However, you **do** need to provide carriage returns in the form of `"\r\n"` after the provided email address.

The modified code would look like this:

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$formcontent = "From: $name" . "\r\n";
$recipient = "abc@gmail.com";
$subject = "Contact Form";
mail($recipient, $subject, $message, $formcontent) or die("Error!");
echo "Thank You!";
?>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Hi, I copied and pasted your code. I am still getting an error message. The inquiry didn't go through.